# how pay network fee for many accounts

Tags: gas

i have crypto pay getaway in my application And we only receive Tether on the (Ethereum and BSC and Tron) networks

The application creates a wallet address for each user

0x123...User1  (Only USDT ERC-20)

0x123...User2  (Only USDT ERC-20)

0x123...User3  (Only USDT ERC-20)

...many

And we have an admin address

0x123...admin (Has Ethereum for Gas fee)

can i pay gas fee with admin wallet for transfer all users wallets to admin wallet?
or any other idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can i pay gas fee with admin wallet for transfer all users wallets to admin wallet?

Yes, this sounds like the description for a [Meta Transaction](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/sending-gasless-transactions). This can be implemented on the Smart Contract level. The general idea is that the admin wallet will be able to make a transaction on behalf of the users and act as a relayer to pay the gas fees for them instead.

[image: https://eips.ethereum.org/assets/eip-3005/meta-txs-directly-to-token-smart-contract.png]